# Correct way to setup my DNS (on GoDaddy) to work with RackServer?

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy, dedicated-server

- I have one server on RackSpace (with a dedicated IP address). (it is essentially a blank Linux box)

  - I have a domain name registered on GoDaddy

What is the best way to setup DNS so when i go to my domain name, it goes to my website on RackSpace?

What I have now: I set DNS forwarding on GoDaddy so my domain name forwards to my dedicated IP address. This seems... wrong somehow because in the address bar the address actually changes to my IP address.

Is there a better way?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Create an A record on your DNS server to point to your dedicated IP address. That should be all you need to do.

Answer (score 3):

Sign in to GoDaddy, go to My Account, select your domain from the list. Under Nameservers, choose "I want to park my domain." That will make GoDaddy's DNS servers "authoritative" for your domain.

Let that update, then look for the section on this same screen called "DNS Manager" and click the "Launch" link. This will open the Zone File Editor. In the A (Host) section, change the IP address on the "@" line to your RackSpace IP.

It could take up to 24 hours for everything to update properly, but this should get you going.

Answer (score 2):

Create a A record for .yourdomain.com pointing to the IP Address.
Create a CNAME for www.yourdomain.com pointing to .yourdomain.com

If you don't want to use a CNAME you can also do an A record pointing to your IP Address.